# How can I access a file that I have created externally? AKA where is the file?

Tags: java, android, file-io, file-location

I'm in the process of trying to create a backup/restore (export/import) process for an SQLite Database App.

Although I appear to have created and populated the file (OK I now know that I have). I cannot see the file in DDMS nor in Windows Explorer. I'd really like to be able to do the latter (see the bottom for a more specific question).

I've successfully written the file and read the file using the following code:

```
package mjt.sqlitetutorial;

        import android.database.Cursor; //+++++ Added
        import android.os.Build;
        import android.os.Environment;
        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.util.Log;        //+++++ Added

        import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
        import java.io.BufferedReader;
        import java.io.File;
        import java.io.FileInputStream;
        import java.io.FileOutputStream;
        import java.io.FileReader;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.io.InputStreamReader;
        import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public int API_VERSION = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (API_VERSION >= 23) {
            ExternalStoragePermissions.verifyStoragePermissions(this);
        }

        final String EXTSTGTAG = "EXTERNSTG";

        File file = getExternalFilesDir("File");
        Log.i(EXTSTGTAG,file.toString());
        //String extstgdirabs = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        String extstgdirpth = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath();
        Log.i(EXTSTGTAG,"<=\nEXTERN STG PUB DIR=>" + extstgdirpth);
        String filepath = extstgdirpth + File.separator + "myfile.txt";
        Log.i(EXTSTGTAG,"Full File Path and name is\n\t" + filepath);

        File f = new File(filepath);
        if(!f.exists() ) {
            Log.i(EXTSTGTAG,"File did not exist (path=" + filepath + ")");
            try {
                f.createNewFile();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(EXTSTGTAG,"Failure Creating New File MSG=" + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        if(f.exists()) {
            Log.i(EXTSTGTAG,"File Already Exists (" + filepath + ")");
            try {
                Log.i(EXTSTGTAG,"Creating FileOutputStream instance.");
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
                Log.i(EXTSTGTAG,"Creating OutputStreamWriter instance from FileOutputStream.");
                OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
                Log.i(EXTSTGTAG,"Adding Data to OutputStreamWriter.");
                osw.append("My Test Data.");

                Log.i(EXTSTGTAG,"Closing OutputStreamWriter.");
                osw.close();
                Log.i(EXTSTGTAG,"Flushing FileOutputStream.");
                fos.flush();
                Log.i(EXTSTGTAG,"Closing FileOutputStream");
                fos.close();
                Log.i(EXTSTGTAG,"All Done OK.");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(EXTSTGTAG, "Failure Trying to write to file." + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else  {
            Log.i(EXTSTGTAG,"File doesn't appear to exist when it should????");
        }
        f.setReadable(true);
        f.setWritable(true);
        if(f.exists()) {
            try {
                byte[] bytes;
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line).append("\n");
                }
                br.close();
                Log.i(EXTSTGTAG,"Read the following data:\n" + sb.toString());
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(EXTSTGTAG,"Failure trying to read file." + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Output to the log (using EXTERN as the filter) shows (note the first run when installing the App run fails but requests and sets permissions. I don't believe this is an issue/cause) :-

```
10-18 12:54:40.159 32393-32393/? I/EXTERNSTG: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/mjt.sqlitetutorial/files/File
10-18 12:54:40.159 32393-32393/? I/EXTERNSTG: <=
                                              EXTERN STG PUB DIR=>/storage/emulated/0/Download
10-18 12:54:40.159 32393-32393/? I/EXTERNSTG: Full File Path and name is
                                                /storage/emulated/0/Download/myfile.txt
10-18 12:54:40.159 32393-32393/? I/EXTERNSTG: File Already Exists (/storage/emulated/0/Download/myfile.txt)
10-18 12:54:40.159 32393-32393/? I/EXTERNSTG: Creating FileOutputStream instance.
10-18 12:54:40.159 32393-32393/? I/EXTERNSTG: Creating OutputStreamWriter instance from FileOutputStream.
10-18 12:54:40.159 32393-32393/? I/EXTERNSTG: Adding Data to OutputStreamWriter.
10-18 12:54:40.159 32393-32393/? I/EXTERNSTG: Closing OutputStreamWriter.
10-18 12:54:40.159 32393-32393/? I/EXTERNSTG: Flushing FileOutputStream.
10-18 12:54:40.159 32393-32393/? I/EXTERNSTG: Closing FileOutputStream
10-18 12:54:40.169 32393-32393/? I/EXTERNSTG: All Done OK.
10-18 12:54:40.169 32393-32393/? I/EXTERNSTG: Read the following data:
                                              My Test Data.
```

**The last line indicating that it has read the file (I assume).** There are no other log messages during the provided messages (many before and after though).

the device that I'm testing this on is a non-rooted HTC One M8s with an SDcard. However, I believe that **/storage/emulated/0/Download**, the directory where the file is being written to is on the internal memory.

With DDMS I don't appear to be able to see this (the actual SD card has a Download**s** directory as opposed to a Download directory).

In Windows explorer I can see both **Internal Storage** and **SD card** as devices under  the **HTC_0PKV1** device.

In Windows Explorer the **Download** directory has (via properties) 0 Directories and Files. Neither read only nor hidden are ticked.

I've tried both with and without the `setReadable` and `setWritable()`.

I've just tried using the file manager on the phone and can now see the file. So more specifically, the question is; **Is there any way excluding rooting the phone and moving the file via file manager on the phone, to access the file via Windows Explorer?**

I should also state that the App will run on tablets, so the method should be generic rather than specific to a device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file becomes visible in Windows explorer after disconnecting and re-connecting the USB cable. I'm not sure if this how MTP is meant to work or it could perhaps be due to ADB as per this snippet:-

> However, if you’ve ever attempted to unlock your device such as to
>   install a new ROM or root it, then you may have at one time or another
>   installed the Android Debug Bridge (ADB) driver on your computer. This
>   driver works great for being able to use the computer to send commands
>   to your device, but it may mess up your easy-peasy file manipulation.

found at [How to Get Your Android Device to Show up in File Explorer (If It Isn’t)](http://www.howtogeek.com/195607/how-to-get-your-android-device-to-show-up-in-file-explorer-if-it-isnt/)